# Trouble with .htpasswd login screen not being displayed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, .htpasswd

I am trying to setup a password protected directory on my localhost.

The `.htaccess` file is located in `/var/www/project/code/server/development` and the `.htpasswd` file is located in the `/home/adarshakb/.htpasswd`

The .htaccess file contains:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName Restricted
AuthUserFile /home/adarshakb/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

and the `.htpasswd` contains:

```
user:HkCKfIOQNlS1E
```

Now, if I go to `http://localhost/project/code/server/development/` It doesnt ask for any authentication and just opens up.

What is wrong here?

Comment: How is the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file configured? Does it allow override, i.e. allow using .htaccess files?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: @MortenHaraldsen yes it does allow. It has the following lines in it. `AccessFileName .htaccess`

Comment: And it has not an AllowOverride None for the directory you are trying to protect?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you lack loads of some modules. To ensure this, try to put garbage in `.htaccess` file, and tell us what's going on. If you have an **error 500**, your modules are loaded properly.

You can print out the loaded modules with this command :

```
apache2ctl -M  2>/dev/null
```

You need at least `mod_authn_file` & `mod_auth_basic`

Comment: I do have the following entries:  auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the line in .htaccess from:

```
AuthName Restricted
```

to

```
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
```

work?

After that, enable htaccess override:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Change the "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" in:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

finally a reload of settings:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```